# Sorting a LinkedList of objects with Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting

Okay so my LinkedList contains objects of the Student Class:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>, Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String gNumber;
    private double gpa;



    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return name.compareTo(s.getName());
    }
```

And i am attempting to use Collections.sort to sort my LinkedList:

```
public class SimpleDatabase implements iSimpleDatabase {
     LinkedList<Student> list = new LinkedList<Student>();
     //code

    @Override
    public void Sort() {
        Collections.sort((List<Student>) list);

    }
```

the sort method would be called from my GUI actionlistener, however when I attempt to sort it i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:   package1.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

On the line that calls the Collections.sort().

I'm sure I'm just being really stupid and all, but I can' for the life of me figure this out and I can't find anything online that explains why it isn't working for me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're using your own `LinkedList` implementation instead of using `java.util.LinkedList` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've defined your own "LinkedList" class in `package1.LinkedList`, which is what you're attempting to pass to `Collections#sort`. Your custom class either needs to implement the `List` interface or you should use `java.util.LinkedList`

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding what you mean, when you say I should use java.util.LinkedList are you saying i'm not using the api LinkedList, but rather my own version of it? and if my own version implements List I can sort it? I implemented List into my LinkedList class and it requires I implement a ton of methods from List that I don't want nor need.

Comment: @Itheyln if that's the case, why not just use the LinkedList implementation provided by Java?

Comment: @Itheyln The best way to make your own list class is not `implements List` but `extends AbstractList`. The first way forces you to override about a zillion methods. The second way only 2, `get` and `size`.

Comment: @Rogue it's for a university project and that would be going against the assignment pretty majorly

Comment: Then you need to make sure you're inheriting `java.util.List` in some way before passing it to `Collections#sort` :)

Answer (score 0):

To use Collections.sort you should have your LinkedList class implement java.util.List,

You can also use the LinkedList implementation from the standard library:

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)